CSS filter property does not work in html2canvas
I currently have a div with an image and to download it I'm using the following code:
  const handleDownloadAll = () => {
    const downloadPromises = [polaroidContainerRef.current].map(
      (previewRef, index) => {
        polaroidImageRef.current.style.zoom = "100%";
        return html2canvas(previewRef).then((canvas) => {
          const imgDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
          const link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = imgDataUrl;
          link.download = `image(${index}).png`;
          link.click();
        });
      }
    );

    Promise.all(downloadPromises)
      .then(() => {
        polaroidImageRef.current.style.zoom = "130%";
        console.log("Download success");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

The div is used to add a border around the image (polarioid style).
However, when adding the CSS filter and zoom property, when downloading the image, the styles are not being picked up.
Can you tell me if it is necessary to carry out any further configuration or if some CSS properties are not supported?
I managed to get around the zoom issue by removing the zoom before downloading the image and adding it afterwards, but I really don't know what to do with the filter.

Here is a list of unsupported properties, it includes filter: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/features#unsupported-css-properties
